# Implementing a login system for web apps and web API with DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, asp.net-web-api, dotnetopenauth

I'm looking for some guidance on what people think are the best set of technologies to use. We are looking to create a web portal to allow customers to register/login with standard credentials or their social accounts (Google, Twitter etc).

Once they are registered and logged in to the portal they can access our different web apps which will know who they are and what permissions they have based on a token. We will also need to secure a set of web APIs using some sort of OAuth mechanism, so the user would possibly create an account on the web app and then create an application which would give them the keys they need to access the API from their own app.

We have a basic portal app using MVC 4 and DotNetOpenAuth which allows a user to create an account and login with either a username and password or their Google, Facebook account etc.
The APIs would be MVC 4 Web APIs

Ideally the whole set up needs to be as simple as possible, I've briefly looked into using Windows Azure Access Control (ACS) as a way to cut out some of the heavy lifting but its hard to tell where exactly it all fits together.

Currently we run an ADFS 2.0 server and WIF to allow web login to our apps but it doesn't seem like it would be an ideal choice when integrating the social login and for securing the web APIs

I guess it could be two quite seperate parts, once they are logged into the portal, how would we go about providing some sort of claims token to the other apps they then access to understand who the user is and what they are allowed to do. And maybe the web API authentication/authorisation is its own entity?

Thanks for your time

Comment: https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityModel.45  This looks like it could fit somewhere in the picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the built in MVC 4 login system and also added JWT token support, when a user is logged in a JWT token containing their claims is stored as a cookie. This is then automatically passed around our sites on the same domain by the browser, when the web API is called from javascript it checks for the token in the headers sent by the browser and either validates it and returns the correct data or returns an unauthorised response.

It doesn't cover all the bases, we can't give trusted third parties access to our web services yet